# Why the program crashes when I am trying to use strcat() in for-loop?

Tags: c, string, loops, concatenation

I have an issue with `strcat`. When I am trying to use it in for-loop it throws a reading access violation.
There is a program as example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

printf("Enter count: ");
int count = 0;
scanf("%d", &count);
char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) str = strcat(str, "a");
```

It works fine with values in kind of 10 or 100 for `count` but it crashes when I use it with 1000 or bigger. Can someone tell me what's the problem?

Comment: how much memory does your program allocate to hold the string?

Comment: This program cannot crash, because it won't even compile. [Edit] and show a [mcve]. Also read this: [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

1. you only allocate space for one character
2. you never initialize the string before calling `strcat`
3. you forgot to include `<stdlib.h>`

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>         // you need this for malloc

int main()
{
  printf("Enter count: ");
  int count = 0;
  scanf("%d", &count);

  char* str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (count + 1));  // allocate count + 1 bytes, the +1 
                                                   // is for the string NUL terminator

  str[0] = 0;                    // initialize the string to an empty string

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    str = strcat(str, "a");

  printf("Result = %s\n", str);  // print the result
}
```

BTW the `(char*)` cast is not needed with `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `str` is not initialized, moreover you are allocating `sizeof(char)` so the size of `str` is only one char.
The function `strcat` concatenates 2 string, `str` and "a" but a string must be terminated by '\0'. So in `strcat` reach the end of string and reads in not allocated memory.